# How do you query across multiple relationships between an "Entity Attribute Value" table and another table?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to wrap my head around querying an "Entity Attribute Value" table like you find in WordPress' `postmeta` table which contains meta data about the posts.

Note that I am not querying the database from within WordPress.

So here's some sample data from the `wp_postmeta` table that shows data from two different events at the same `_EventVenueID`:

```
+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key          | meta_value          |
+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 3914    | 422     | _EventStateDate   | 2016-01-27 01:00:00 |
| 3915    | 422     | _EventEndDate     | 2016-01-27 02:00:00 |
| 3400    | 422     | _EventVenueID     | 333                 |
| 3916    | 422     | _EventOrganizerID | 410                 |
| 3917    | 423     | _EventStartDate   | 2017-01-28 01:00:00 |
| 3918    | 423     | _EventEndDate     | 2017-01-28 02:00:00 |
| 3401    | 423     | _EventVenueID     | 333                 |
| 3919    | 423     | _EventOrganizerID | 411                 |
+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

And here is some sample data from a truncated version of the `wp_posts` table:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
| ID      | post_title | post_type       | post_status |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 422     | Picnic     | tribe_events    | publish     |
| 423     | Concert    | tribe_events    | publish     |
| 411     | Bob Jones  | tribe_organizer | publish     |
| 410     | Mary Smith | tribe_organizer | publish     |
| 333     | Park       | tribe_venue     | publish     |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

As you can see, there are three kinds of entities: events, organizers and venues. Each event can have one venue and one or more organizers. Also notice that `wp_posts.ID` column indexes the `wp_postmeta.post_id` column as well as the `wp_postmeta.meta_value` column.

So, if I want to pull the event data for a particular venue (in this case, the Park), I can do that with this query:

```
SELECT pm1.meta_value AS _EventVenueID,
  p.post_title,
  pm2.meta_value AS _EventStartDate,
  pm3.meta_value AS _EventEndDate,
  pm4.meta_value AS _EventOrganizerID
  FROM wp_posts p
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm1 ON (p.ID = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key='_EventVenueID')
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON (p.ID = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key='_EventStartDate')
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm3 ON (p.ID = pm3.post_id AND pm3.meta_key='_EventEndDate')
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm4 ON (p.ID = pm4.post_id AND pm4.meta_key='_EventOrganizerID')
  WHERE p.post_type = 'tribe_events' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  HAVING _EventVenueID = 333
```

Now let's say I also want to select the name of the organizer as a column, too. So, in other words, I want to relate the `_EventOrganizerId` in the `wp_postmeta` table to data that is in the `wp_posts` table so I can also pull out the `post_title` for the organizer associated with the event.

How do I do this?

*UPDATE* for question on desired output in comments:

Currently, I get an output like this on a row result:

```
  [
    '333',
    'Picnic',
    '2016-01-27 01:00:00',
    '2016-01-27 02:00:00',
    '410'
  ],
```

What I want to get is the same thing, but with the name of the organizer, too:

```
  [
    '333',
    'Picnic',
    '2016-01-27 01:00:00',
    '2016-01-27 02:00:00',
    '410',
    'Mary Smith'
  ],
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: See update at bottom of question for your answer @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just more of the same...

```
SELECT pm1.meta_value _EventVenueID
     , p1.post_title event_type
     , p2.post_title organiser
     , pm2.meta_value _EventStartDate
     , pm3.meta_value _EventEndDate
     , pm4.meta_value _EventOrganizerID
  FROM wp_posts p1 
  JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 
    ON p1.ID = pm1.post_id 
   AND pm1.meta_key = '_EventVenueID'
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 
    ON p1.ID = pm2.post_id 
   AND pm2.meta_key = '_EventStartDate'
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_postmeta pm3 
    ON p1.ID = pm3.post_id 
   AND pm3.meta_key = '_EventEndDate'
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_postmeta pm4 
    ON p1.ID = pm4.post_id 
   AND pm4.meta_key = '_EventOrganizerID'

  LEFT
  JOIN wp_posts p2
    ON p2.id = pm4.meta_value 

 WHERE p1.post_type = 'tribe_events' 
   AND p1.post_status = 'publish'
   AND pm1.meta_value = 333;
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.

I'm a hobbyist programmer. I only know basic sql syntax and don't understand what's going on with this query. What  do you call this kind of query so I can search about it and learn more? It looks like it's just one big join of a table to itself over and over?

Comment: I suspect that most of us are amateurs here ;-) It's a sort of pivot table query, but really it's just a big query. It's an (almost) inevitable consequence of EAV. There is actually another, simpler way to write this, but this method is faster.

Comment: One follow up question. It's possible for an event to have more than one organizer. How do I handle that?

Comment: @StevieD Hm, I think my example assumes that (entity,attribute) is unique. I think you'd have to say that one person is event_organiser1 and the other is event_organiser2